# Color a div without coloring the padding area

Tags: css

If I have a div:

```
<div></div>
```

And some css to give it a color:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then it colors the padding area as well. Is there a way to avoid this without changing the border or margin properties?

Comment: You could use a wrapper div and either give the wrapper a 20px padding or the inner div a 20px margin.

Comment: You could fake it if you don't mind matching the uncolored area to the background like http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rx2fk06f/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
background-clip: content-box;
```

Comment: How did I go so long without knowing this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create two squares with different sizes, one inside the other.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/5ouvn063/2/

**CSS**

```
div.inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
div.outer {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: blue;        
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

In fact you could even remove the width and height of the outer div and float the element left.

**EDIT**

```
div.inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
div.outer {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left; 
    text-align:center;    
}
```

**DEMO#2** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/5ouvn063/3/